# Equal spacing between columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am beginner web developer (html and css).
My project is in Bootstrap 4.
I have 5 columns in one line.

I have this code:

```
<section class="related-product">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 h-100 pt-4">
                <h4 class="float-left">Podobne produkty</h4>
                <span class="pl-3 related-product-count">(20 produktów)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="mt-5 w-100">
                    <div class="w-100 mb-3">
                        <img src="img/product1.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-name-box">
                        <a class="product-card-new-info" href="#">Nowość</a><br/>
                        <div class="product-card-name pt-2">
                            <a href="#">Szafka mimimo</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-category"><a href="#">Stojąca</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="mt-5 w-100">
                    <div class="w-100 mb-3">
                        <img src="img/product2.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-name-box">
                        <a class="product-card-new-info" href="#">Nowość</a><br/>
                        <div class="product-card-name pt-2">
                            <a href="#">Szafka mimimo</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-category"><a href="#">Stojąca</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="mt-5 w-100">
                    <div class="w-100 mb-3">
                        <img src="img/product3.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-name-box">
                        <a class="product-card-new-info" href="#">Nowość</a><br/>
                        <div class="product-card-name pt-2">
                            <a href="#">Szafka mimimo</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-category"><a href="#">Stojąca</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="mt-5 w-100">
                    <div class="w-100 mb-3">
                        <img src="img/product4.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-name-box">
                        <a class="product-card-new-info" href="#">Nowość</a><br/>
                        <div class="product-card-name pt-2">
                            <a href="#">Szafka mimimo</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-category"><a href="#">Stojąca</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="mt-5 w-100">
                    <div class="w-100 mb-3">
                        <img src="img/product5.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-name-box">
                        <a class="product-card-new-info" href="#">Nowość</a><br/>
                        <div class="product-card-name pt-2">
                            <a href="#">Szafka mimimo</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-card-category"><a href="#">Stojąca</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

How can you make equal spacing between the columns (on LG and XL)?
How can I do at smaller resolutions (xs sm, md) of 1 or 2 columns in a row (responsive)?

How can I make it?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, I would suggest you try `Table` instead, you may try [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/)

However, for smaller `Col` you may refer to link [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) go to Grid Classes, there you are able to chose the best option according to your targeting resolution.

If you leave it as default `Col`, it will divide the space equally, lets say:

```
<Row>
  <Col></Col>
  <Col></Col>
</Row>
```

In this case, both `Col` will share 50% of your space that you allocated.

For responsive, you may get the overall css [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/), under *[Grid Option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-options)* and *[Responsive column resets](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-responsive-resets)* Try to drag your browser to see the performance :)